# ggplot is not graphing a vertical line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph in ggplot2 where the x-axis represents month-day combinations, the dots represent y-values for two different groups.

When graphing my original data set using this code,

```
ggplot(graphing.df, aes(MONTHDAY, y.var, color = GROUP)) +
          geom_point() + 
          ylab(paste0(""))+ 
          scale_x_discrete(breaks = function(x) x[seq(1, length(x), by = 15)])+ 
        theme(legend.text = element_blank(),
              legend.title = element_blank()) + 
          geom_vline(xintercept = which(graphing.df$MONTHDAY == "12-27")[1], col='red', lwd=2)
```

I get this graph where the vertical line is not showing.

[image]

When I tried to create a reproducible example using the following code...

```
df <- data.frame(MONTHDAY = c("01-01", "01-01", "01-02", "01-02", "01-03", "01-03"),
                                TYPE = rep(c("A", "B"), 3),
                                VALUE = sample(1:10, 6, replace = TRUE))
      
      verticle_line <- "01-02"
      
      ggplot(df, aes(MONTHDAY, VALUE, color = TYPE)) +
          geom_point() + 
          #geom_vline(xintercept = which(df$MONTHDAY == verticle_line)[1], col='red', lwd=2)+ 
          geom_vline(xintercept = which(df$MONTHDAY == verticle_line), col='blue', lwd=2)
```

The vertical line is showing, but now its showing in the wrong place

[image]

In my original data set I have two values for each month-day combination (representing each of the two groups).  The month-day combination column is a character vector, it is not a factor and does not have levels.

Comment: See what `which(df$MONTHDAY == verticle_line)` returns. the vertical line is plotted there...

Comment: I get the following error ```Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
  no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "factor"```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way. It subsets the data keeping only the rows of interest and plots the vertical line defined by `MONTHDAY`.

```
library(ggplot2)

verticle_line <- "01-02"

ggplot(df, aes(MONTHDAY, VALUE, color = TYPE)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(data = subset(df, MONTHDAY == verticle_line),
             mapping = aes(xintercept = MONTHDAY), color = 'blue', size = 2)
```

[image]

**Data**

I will repost the data creation code, this time setting the RNG seed in order to make the example reproducible.

```
set.seed(2020)
df <- data.frame(MONTHDAY = c("01-01", "01-01", "01-02", "01-02", "01-03", "01-03"),
                                TYPE = rep(c("A", "B"), 3),
                                VALUE = sample(1:10, 6, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: i get the following error when I try and run this code ```Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
  no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "factor"```

Comment: @user8304241 What is your version of R? With R 4.0.0 the default for `data.frame()` changed to `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. In the question you say that the x axis is *a discrete axis of character vectors*. Check the class of `MONTHDAY`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your line is not showing up where you expect is because you are setting the value of `xintercept=` via the output of the `which()` function.  `which()` returns the *index value* where the condition is true.  So in the case of your reproducible example, you get the following:

```
> which(df$MONTHDAY == verticle_line)
[1] 3 4
```

It returns a vector indicating that in `df$MONTHDAY`, indexes 3 and 4 in that vector are true.  So your code below:

```
geom_vline(xintercept = which(df$MONTHDAY == verticle_line)...
```

Reduces down to this:

```
geom_vline(xintercept = c(3,4)...
```

Your MONTHDAY axis is not formatted as a date, but treated as a discrete axis of character vectors.  In this case `xintercept=c(3,4)` applied to a discrete axis draws two vertical lines at x intercepts equivalent to the 3rd and 4th discrete position on that axis:  in other words, "01-03" and... some unknown 4th position that is not observable within the axis limits.

How do you fix this?  Just take out `which()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(MONTHDAY, VALUE, color = TYPE)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = verticle_line, col='blue', lwd=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can get the corresponding values of 'MONTHDAY' after subsetting

```
ggplot(df, aes(MONTHDAY, VALUE, color = TYPE)) +
      geom_point() + 
      geom_vline(xintercept = df$MONTHDAY[df$MONTHDAY == verticle_line],
                        col='blue', lwd=2)
```

[image]